# Slashes in a string PHP

Tags: php

I have looked everywhere for a simple way of doing this and just cannot get it correct.
In php I want to assign a name to a variable and then replace the name in the string with the variable. The slashes are causing syntax errors.

```
//Assign the name to a variable.
$patient_name = "John_Doe";

//Replace the name in this string with the variable.
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"John_Doe.pdf\"");
```

Comment: Didn't got your question but why you need "\" where you can use `'` instead?

Comment: Not sure I follow you.

Comment: He's asking why you don't choose to use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`) around the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within double quotes, you can encapsulate variables using braces as such:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='{$patient_name}.pdf'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the variable inside it. Like this

```
<?php
$patient_name = "John_Doe.pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$patient_name");
                                          --------^
```

Comment: Let me try that. i sec/. Brilliant. I just did not have a clue! Thank you very much!!!